# Average day values of last month as a SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I got a table with two columns, `timestamp` (like '1405184196') and `value`.

I've saved some measured values.

```
$day= time()-84600;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT timestamp, value FROM table WHERE timestamp >= "'.$day.'" ORDER BY timestamp ASC');
```

This is how I get all values for the last 24h.

But is it possible to get average day values for the last month with a SQL statement or do I have to select all values of the last month and calculate the average of each day via PHP?

Comment: Check for the AVG group function

Comment: But how do i group? I just have a couple of timestamp values. So i dont have clear days or months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues with [Anish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24712174/428543):

1) This won't work if date+time is being stored in the `timestamp` field.

2) It assumes the OP means last month i.e June, May etc and not the last say 30 days.

This solves those issues:

```
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`, AVG(value)
FROM table 
WHERE `timestamp` >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
GROUP BY DATE(`timestamp)
```

**EDIT**

Since the timestamp is a unix timestamp and the OP would like a calendar month:

```
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIX(`timestamp`)) as `timestamp`, AVG(value)
FROM table 
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIX(`timestamp`)) = MONTH(NOW() - 1)
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIX(`timestamp))
```

Comment: Thanks. The timestamp-field has the content like '1405184196'. And yes I mean a calendar-month; like all data for July - not the last 30 days...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:-

```
SELECT timestamp, AVG(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY timestamp
HAVING MONTH(timestamp) = MONTH(NOW()) - 1;
```

This query calculates average for last month.

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d840/1)**